# Simple Sinatra proxy not behaving as expected with jQuery POST calls

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I have what is a simple proxy written in Sinatra.  This block is designed to pass through all calls to api/*.  Things work as expected locally.  However, when I push to server, strange things start happening.  a jQuery call using $.post leads to a GET request to the API, instead of the expected POST.  From the "proxy" server logs, I see a single jQuery call resulting in two log items, a POST and then a GET, the result of the latter of which seems to be what jQuery gets back.  I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on here, would be amazing to get some hints.

```
# Proxy all requests to /api/*
proxy = lambda do |path|
  uri = URI('http://' + HOST + '/api/' + path)
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params) if (request.request_method == 'GET')

  # New request data
  data = {
    :url => 'http://' + uri.host + ':' + uri.port.to_s + uri.request_uri,
    :method => request.request_method,
    :headers => request_headers,
    :query => uri.query
  }

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

  if request.request_method == 'POST'
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.request_uri
    request.body.rewind
    req.form_data = CGI.parse request.body.read
  else
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  end

  # Passthrough headers
  data[:headers]['host'] = uri.host + ':' + uri.port.to_s
  data[:headers].each { |key, val| req[key] = val }

  # Log request data
  res = http.request req

  # Return
  status res.code
  content_type 'application/json'
  headers res.to_hash
  body res.body
end

get '/api/*', &proxy
post '/api/*', &proxy
```

dafa